# Java hashcode() strings collision

Tags: java, hashcode, collision

I do not know much about hashcodes. I found this code which prints the collisions.

Can you please tell me what are collisions and how to reduce it?
Why should we use hashcodes?

```
public static int getHash(String str, int limit)
{
    int hashCode = Math.abs(str.hashCode()%(limit));
    return hashCode;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int hashLimit = 10000;
    int stringsLimit = 10000;
    String[] arr = new String[hashLimit];
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    Random r = new Random(2);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < stringsLimit ; i++ )
    {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++ )
        {
            char c = (char)(35+60*r.nextDouble());
            buf.append(c);
        }
        test.add(buf.toString());
        //System.out.println(buf.toString());
    }
    int collisions = 0;
    for ( String curStr : test )
    {
        int hashCode = getHash(curStr,hashLimit);
        if ( arr[hashCode] != null && !arr[hashCode].equals(curStr) )
        {
            System.out.println("collision of ["+arr[hashCode]+"] ("+arr[hashCode].hashCode()+" = "+hashCode+") with ["+curStr+"] ("+curStr.hashCode()+" = "+hashCode+")");
            collisions++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[hashCode] = curStr;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Collisions: "+collisions);
}
```

Comment: Regarding your 3 questions, the best answer for all 3 questions would be on wikipedia.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Can you please tell me what are collisions and how to reduce it?

Collisions are when two non-equal objects have the same hash code. They're a fact of life - you need to deal with it.

> Why should we use hashcodes?

Because they make it quick to look up values by key, basically. A hash table can use a hash code to very quickly get the set of possible key matches down to a *very small set* (often just one), at which point you need to check for *actual* key equality.

You should *never* assume that two hash codes being equal means the objects they were derived from are equal. Only the reverse is true: assuming a correct implementation, if two objects give *different* hash codes, then they are *not* equal.

Comment: @HelloWorld: Well you're explicitly limiting the hash code to have *at most* 10,000 different values. That's a pretty poor starting point. It's not clear what you're trying to do, but if you're going to write your own kind of hash table, I'd do a bit more research on it first. You *must* be able to cope with collisions, and there are various different approaches for that.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the other part of your question: To reduce the chance of collisions you should implement a hashing algorithm that provides an even distribution of hash codes over the set of possible inputs.

For example, supposing you implemented a naive `hashCode()` method for hashing `MyString` instances:

```
public class MyString {
  private final char[] arr;

  // Constructor and other methods.

  public int hashCode() {
    return arr.length == 0 ? 0 : (int) arr[0];
  }
}
```

In this example only the **first character** is used to create the hash code.  Therefore, if you were to hash the strings: "apple", "anaconda", "anecdote" they would all produce the same hash value.  A more efficient hash code would inspect all the letters in the character array to determine a hash code value, which would hopefully reduce the chance of a collision.

Answer (score 0):

We have a "collision" if two <strike>different</strike> *non-equal* objects have the same hashcode. This *may* be a problem, for example when try to use both objects as keys in a Hashmap.

Comment: @HelloWorld improve the hashing function can reduce collisions, but usually the simplest thing to do is to use a larger array. i.e. a lower loading factor.

Comment: @HelloWorld, well, the code is artificially limiting it via the second argument to the `getHash` method.  So you can reduce it by increasing (or eliminating) that limit.

Comment: @Kirk Woll thank you..I reduced the limit and the collisions reduced. But are there any other possible ways to do it?